# BitmapImage: Accessing closed StreamSource

Tags: c#, wpf, arrays, bitmapimage

I'm using the following code trying to convert my BitmapImage to a byte[] so I can save it in my MS SQL Database.

```
    public static byte[] BufferFromImage(BitmapImage img)
    {
        if (img == null)
            return null;

            byte[] result = null;
            using (Stream stream = img.StreamSource)
            {
                if (stream != null && stream.Length > 0)
                {
                    using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream))
                    {
                        result = br.ReadBytes((int)(stream.Length));
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Sadly this doesn't work as img.StreamSource is disposed when I try to access it in the if-statement, resulting in an exception "Cannot access a disposed file".

My call:
`BufferFromImage(imgLogo.Source as BitmapImage);`

How can I avoid this?

Comment: It seems to be garbage-collected or disposed before passing to the method. Could you post the code for previous workings with this BitmapImage ?

Comment: @Dmitriy Reznik: I'm using DevExpress' WPF ImageEdit Control for that. I've added the code.

Comment: Try using EditValue instead of Source.

Comment: Still results in Exception "Cannot access a closed file."

Comment: Could you give any more specifics on the usage of ImageEdit control ? Image shouldn't be disposed earlier than it's no longer in use. Since ImageEdit is resulting in disposed bitmapImage, it maybe is going out of scope and garbage-collected.

Comment: The ImageEdit-Control is placed inside a GroupFrame on a UserControl. As soon as I hit a BarItem in my Ribbon called "Save" (in the save-method), I want to access the image.

Comment: The usage seems to be correct. You should debug and see why the Source gets disposed.

Comment: The source gets disposed as soon as I call the BufferFromImage()-Method... Nothing is happening with the image or the control before.
`setting.Logo = imgLogo.HasImage ? Utilities.BufferFromImage(imgLogo.Source as BitmapImage) : null;`

Comment: Strange. I've seen somewhere BitmapImage being sent with ref parameter. Worth a try :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally managed to get it working:

```
    public static byte[] BufferFromImage(BitmapImage img)
    {
        byte[] result = null;

        if (img != null)
        {
            using(MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(img));
                encoder.Save(memStream);

                result = memStream.ToArray();
            }

        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Use `memStream.ToArray()`, not `memStream.GetBuffer()`. The buffer returned from `GetBuffer` will include unused (but allocated) bytes at the end. Not only will this take up more space in the database, it may cause loading the image to fail (if the image loader is dependent on the input data length).

Comment: You should still dispose of the stream once you are done. That was the point of the using statement before.