# Resize BitmapImage

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, image, bitmap

I have this method, I want to load a picture from disk, then resize it to a smaller size and save it to a byte array, to be saved into a blob in a mysql table. As far i can tell it is resizing but when i save it into the table i can see that the byte array is the original file size. But i only want to save thumbnails in the table.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Load and resize image into a byte array.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bitmap"></param>
    /// <param name="FileName"></param>
    /// <param name="Width"></param>
    /// <param name="Height"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Byte[] LoadImageInToByteArray(string FileName, int Width, int Height)
    {
        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();

        System.IO.FileStream photoStream = new System.IO.FileStream(FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.Read);

        bitmap.BeginInit();
        bitmap.StreamSource = photoStream;
        bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmap.DecodePixelHeight = Height;
        bitmap.DecodePixelWidth = Width;
        byte[] buffer = BufferFromImage(bitmap);
        bitmap.EndInit();
        return buffer;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert BitImage into Byte Array.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="imageSource"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Byte[] BufferFromImage(BitmapImage imageSource)
    {
        byte[] result = null;

        if (imageSource != null)
        {
            using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(imageSource));
                encoder.Save(memStream);

                result = memStream.ToArray();
            }

        }

        return result;
    }
```

This function is called by this line:

```
yelloDataSet.EmployeesPicture[index].Picture =
    helperClass.LoadImageInToByteArray(helperClass.OpenFileDialogSingle("Abrir Imaginen."),150,150);
```

What am i missing here ?

Comment: [BufferFromImage()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9847529/1997232) ? If yes, then it's likely not using new bitmap width or height, rather underlying stream is copying one to one.

Comment: Try to call `EndInit()` before `BufferFromImage()`.

Comment: That gives me a empty Byte[] ...

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work before, it returns unmodified stream of bytes. My guess you must call `EndInit()`. The question is why byte array is empty. What you call *empty*? Is it `null` or is it `Length == 0` ? Also you didn't confirm how `BufferFromImage()` method look like (it may be worth to include it into question).

Comment: I will add BufferFromImage to the question. from the debugger: buffer {byte[0]} byte[]

Comment: Your BufferFromImage method returns the bytes from the original stream. That will obviously give you exactly the original bytes from the image file. You'll have to encode a new buffer as in the method linked by Sinatr.

Comment: Was using the sugested solution from Clemens, Yes i can now read the stream efter .EndInit() but still my original problem is there, it saves the original stream instead of the resized one.

Comment: You should use the BufferFromImage method from the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9847529/1136211), not from the question.

Comment: Yes ... that works now, Thank you

Answer (score -1):

```
     public static MemoryStream ResizeImageFromStream(Stream stream, String nameOfFile, int width, int height)
{
    try
    {
        Image img;
        double ratio;
    int newWidth;
    int newHeight;      
        Graphics gfx = null;
        img = Image.FromStream(stream);
        Image Photo = new Bitmap(img, width, height);
        Encoder myEncoder;
        EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter;
        EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters;
        ImageCodecInfo myImageCodecInfo;

        myImageCodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo(nameOfFile.Substring(nameOfFile.LastIndexOf(".")).ToLower());
        myEncoder = Encoder.Quality;
        myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
        myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 87L);
        myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
        MemoryStream mstr = new MemoryStream();

        gfx = Graphics.FromImage(Photo);
        gfx.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        gfx.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        gfx.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        gfx.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        gfx.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

        ImageCodecInfo[] info = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
        EncoderParameters encParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
        encParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, m_imageQuality);

        img.Dispose();
        Photo.Save(mstr, info[1],encParams);
        Photo.Dispose();

        return mstr;

    }
    catch
    {
        return new MemoryStream();
    }


}
```

> You can convert memorystream to bytes

Comment: That doesn't make much sense in a WPF application. Besides that, you could have edited and undeleted your other answer instead of writing a new one.